# squid-deb-proxy 503 service Unavailable

Tags: apt, squid-deb-proxy

I have installed `squid-deb-proxy` in order to create a cache of packages. The command `sudo apt-get update` produces errors such as

```
Err http://mirror.dhakacom.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
   503  Service Unavailable
```

and

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources
   503  Service Unavailable
```

Here are the contents of my `02proxy` file:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy
Acquire { HTTP { Proxy "http://localhost:8000"; }; };
```

However, with `squid-deb-proxy` removed, I face no error. What do I need to do in order to set up `squid-deb-proxy`?

Comment: What's the configuration of squid and squid-deb?

Comment: I didn't change any any thing. It's just the basic config.

Comment: I moved on. Now I use apt-cacher-ng. It works smoothly. Just for information If anyone is curious to know. :-)

Comment: I am having same issue!!!